# How to combine two PHP 'foreach' loops

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to parse a really simple HTML document with some xpath. There are a total of 20 images and 20 links. My only goal is to get each link applied to it's corresponding image.

My current code below is returning [each image a bunch of times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEKM2.png). So for example, that first image, which is currently showing 20 times, has a different link applied to it with each instance. So instance #1 of image #1, has link #1 applied to it, instance #2 of image #1 has link #2 applied to it, and so on.

What I want to do is include each image once and apply the corresponding link to it, so I have 20 images, with their corresponding links applied to them. I'm pretty sure I need to combine my two foreach functions, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any help would be awesome, thanks guys.

```
foreach ( $images = $xpath->query("//div[@class='image']//a//img") as $image )
    {
foreach ( $links = $xpath->query("//div[@class='image']//a") as $link )
        echo "<a href='" . $link->getAttribute( 'href' ) . "'><img src='" . $image->getAttribute( 'src' ) . "'</a>", "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Why not just query the anchor node for its image subnode?

Comment: Sorry Ignacio, I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: I believe you're also not closing your img HTML tag. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Ignacio's idea...

First, query for all anchor elements containing images

```
$anchors = $xpath->query('//div[@class="image"]//a[img]');
```

Then, use the anchor as the context for the image search

```
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $images = $anchor->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $img = $images->item(0);

    printf('<a href="%s"><img src="%s"></a>%s',
           $anchor->getAttribute('href'),
           $img->getAttribute('src'),
           PHP_EOL);
}
```

### Update

To me, this seems a much more appropriate job for an XSL transformation

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phil. How do I echo out the results?

Comment: Thank you Phil. Someone else recently recommended XSL to me. I have no idea where to begin so I'm googling for a tutorial. Not much out there. For context, this simple HTML document I'm trying to parse is on an external site, and with my limited knowledge xpath seemed to be perfect for what I wanted to do. Can you give me a quick *one-liner* explaining when to use xPath vs when to use XSL?

Comment: @rocky *Use XSLT when you want to transform one document into another*. The [W3Schools tutorial](http://wwww.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) is one of the better ones on that site

Answer (score 1):

OK so if I understand correctly, after doing the xpath queries you'd end up with two arrays, each with the same number of elements, and they're all matched, meaning $images[x] needs $links[x] for any value of x.

Something like this may work:

```
$images = $xpath->query("//div[@class='image']//a//img");
$links = $xpath->query("//div[@class='image']//a");

foreach ( $images as $index => $image )
{
  echo "<a href='" . $links[$index]->getAttribute( 'href' ) . "'><img src='" . $images[$index]->getAttribute( 'src' ) . "'</a>", "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please comment when downvoting, it helps improve our answers.

Comment: Don't rely on same length collections. There may be (and most probably are) more items in the `$links` node list

Comment: Good point, that's why I said "two arrays, each with the same number of elements". It's a precondition for this code to work. To be honest I like the other solution better :) Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Hey Roadmaster, yep, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. In this case, there *are* exactly 20 images and 20 links, but I'd also like to learn how to do this when that *isn't* the case, like Phil mentioned above. Anyways, thanks for the answer man :)

Comment: That code is actually throwing me this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array (on the final line - *echo "<a href='" . $links[$index]->getAttribute( 'href' ) . "'><img src='" . $images[$index]->getAttribute( 'src' ) . "'</a>", "\n";*